# Tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}_2$-vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Given the set $X$, let $\mathbb{Z}_2^X$ be the set of functions $\alpha:X \to \mathbb{Z}_2$, which is naturally a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Now define a linear map $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_2^X \otimes \mathbb{Z}_2^Y \to \mathbb{Z}_2^{X\times Y}$ by $$\varphi(\alpha \otimes \beta)(x,y)=\alpha(x)\beta(y). $$

I feel like $\varphi$ is actually a bijection, but I don't know how to prove it. Maybe we need some hypothesis on the sets $X$ and $Y$, like some kind of finiteness.